# How can I distinguish the first image in an image field in a Twig template?

Tags: 8, media, theming

I have a custom field formatter for an image field. The Twig template for the image field is the following:

```
{% for item in items %}
  {{ item.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

Each image is then formatted by the following template:

```
<li data-src={{ fullimage }}><img src="{{ thumbnail }}" /></li>
```

But what I want to do is to format the first image of the field in a different way. I found how I could change the for loop in the template and use `loop.first` to treat the first image differently. But the formatting I want to change is in the inner template that formats each image, the one I call with `item.content`. In the outer template for the entire image field I can distinguish the first image, in the inner template I have no idea how to check for that or how to transfer that information from the outer to the inner template.

Any idea on how I can solve this and format only the first image in a different way?

Comment: What is the filename for the first template?

Comment: @kiamlaluno `field-image.html.twig`, but I'm overriding the template from my custom field formatter, not a theme.

Comment: Sounds like you should implement a custom field formatter. Just copy the default from core over to a custom module, rename everything properly and then jump in to the foreach that there is. Similar to what's been done here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/171471/15055

Answer (score 5):

This code in a `node.html.twig` template will display only the *first* value of an image field that has multiple values:

```
{{ content.field_yourfieldname.0 }}
```

This will only display the *second* value:

```
{{ content.field_yourfieldname.1 }}
```

[Source](https://sqndr.github.io/d8-theming-guide/twig/twig-basics.html#printing-a-variable)

*Edit: apparently that wasn't really the question, my apologies.*

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do, is to add a suggestion for the image field, based of the delta value of the field item.

Drupal has [extensive documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2186401) on working with suggestions in Drupal 8.

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate about the "delta value" of the field ? What is it and did they contain the index of the current iterated item ?