# How to only show the first paragraph item?

Tags: views, paragraphs

I have a content type and attached is paragraph type with the setting of unlimited paragraph items.

On creating a page view of nodes and adding a relationship with the known paragraphs.

The views page shows all paragraph items attached to the node. How do I only show the first paragraph image item? **I have a group of nodes that need to show the node title and the paragraph items first image in the page view**

[image]

[image]

I have tried to filter it using image_first as suggest and I still be all the images on the paragraph type showing. See image

[image]

Comment: You have a content type with a paragraphs field offering different paragraph types and only want to show the first item no matter what type that is? Or you have an image field (unlimited) in a certain paragraph type and only want the first image to be shown?

Comment: Thanks for your reply to answer your question, `Or you have an image field (unlimited) in a certain paragraph type and only want the first image to be shown?`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I only show the first image of an image field in the teaser?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/171466/how-can-i-only-show-the-first-image-of-an-image-field-in-the-teaser)

Comment: Then simply use that image formatter from the answer to the linked question above.

Comment: Field formatters are available in views as well.

Comment: Ok, this a different question. The one image formatter  removes multiple images that are attached to one field type and it works fine. But the view page has a collection nodes and each paragraph element has one image attached. Please see image above

Comment: Actually it would be the exact same principle. Copy the default formatter over into your own module and add one `break` add the end of the `foreach` in the view elements function.

Comment: I have just tried it see image above. Thanks for helping

Comment: No, you haven't. That's Image First. You have to copy the default Paragraphs formatter to create your own "Paragraph First" formatter for the paragraphs field.

Comment: Ooh! You are right I have not done it that way at all. I will do as you say and if it works and I will change the post. Thanks

Comment: Nah, if you get it done, post the formatter code as an answer, it will help others!